# Proof of the inverse of a matrix multiplication from the relation $\operatorname{inv}(A) =\operatorname{adj}(A)/\det(A)$

Tags: matrices

I am trying to prove that (1) $(\mathbf{AB})^{-1}=\mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ using the relation (2)$$ \mathbf{A}^{-1}=\text{adj}\mathbf{A}/\det \mathbf{A}$$ where $\operatorname{adj}\mathbf{A}$ is the adjugate of $\mathbf{A}$, and $\det\mathbf{A}\neq 0$

For the special case where both matrices are $n$ x $n$, I came down to try to prove that (3)  $$\text{det}(\mathbf{AB})(i/j)=\sum_{k=1}^n\text{det}\mathbf{A}(i/k)\det\mathbf{B}(k/j)$$
where $\det\mathbf{A}(i/j)$ is the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$ minus row $i$ and column $j$.

I have checked the validity of this relation for a $2×2$ matrix, but cannot prove it in general.  On the other hand, is there a more straightforward way of proving (1) using (2) without going through (3)?

Comment: Why would you want to prove such a simple one using the classic adjoint? Won't it be simpler to use uniqueness of inverses?

Comment: (1) is a general statement valid in *any* (multiplicative) group.

Comment: My question is really how to prove (3)

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way: Suppose that $A, B$ are $n \times n$ matrices such that $AB$ is invertible.
This means that $\det(AB) \neq 0$ and hence, by the formula you gave we have
$$
\begin{align}
(AB)^{-1} 
&= \frac{\operatorname{adj}(AB)}{\det(AB)} \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{adj}(B) \cdot \operatorname{adj}(A)}{\det(B) \cdot \det(A)} \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{adj}(B)}{\det(B)} \cdot \frac{\operatorname{adj}(A)}{\det(A)} \\
&= B^{-1} A^{-1} 
\end{align}
$$
by using $\operatorname{adj}(AB) = \operatorname{adj}(B)\operatorname{adj}(A)$.

Comment: One would have to explain how did you go from adj$(AB)\;$ in the first line to adj$(B)\,$adj$(A)$ in the second line.

Comment: It's a known property I specifically mentioned and I guessed that OP would know it -- if not, there is an elementary proof for this case on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties).

Comment: How do you get  adj(AB)= adj(B)adj(A)

Comment: That is explained in the comment right above yours.

Comment: The only elementary proof on Wikipedia I see uses the fact  that inv(AB)=inv(B)inv(A), which is what we are trying to prove here.  The other proof makes a reference to the Binet-Cauchy relation.

Answer (score 1):

For any invertible matrix $\;X$, its inverse is denoted by $\;X^{-1}$. Thus, the inverse of the product $\;AB\;$ of square matrices $\;A,\,B\;$ is $\;(AB)^{-1}$. Yet

$$(AB)\cdot(B^{-1}A^{-1})=A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=AIA^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$$

using associativity, and thus also $\;B^{-1}A^{-1}\;$ is the inverse of $\;AB$. By uniqueness of the inverse, $\;(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}\;$ and we're done.

Comment: I am familiar with this proof, I was looking for a proof using (2).  Also, if either det(A) or det(B)=0, then det(AB)=0 and AB has no inverse.  How does the above proof covers this case?

Comment: The basic assumption, of course, is that both $\;A,\,B\;$ are invertible. It is *exactly* the very same assumption done with the other method, as you must divide by the determinant...